# Passing {@ID} in a Form Action Button URLredirect

Tags: form, url, parameter

Can anyone explain how to properly pass the list item ID in a url when redirecting the url from a form action button? Here's my url:

`onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={../../_layouts/ IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={fbaaa67e-2560-4c1e-a9d3-e6331d745522}&ID={@ItemId}&TemplateID={10a14bcf-f3ee-4b20-a92a-2d4bbeebb81c}')}" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking on a NewForm page, the @ID won't be defined yet so you can't use it in a redirection url. You'd need a script that submits the data, queries for the ID with the information submitted then do a redirect. Fortunately there is a jQuery solution to do that in the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPRedirectWithID&referringTitle=Documentation) library, SPRedirectWithID.

If you are on a View or Edit page, you'd use @ID.

Comment: I've tried that method from the edit form, but receive a correlation error. Any reason why that would throw an error?

Comment: And when I get it to work, it redirects me to the dispForm.aspx of the last item created. Thoughts?